# How to shield from WiFi signal

Tags: microcontroller, wifi

I'm working on a device which uses Raspberry Pi Pico W and connects to WiFi.
I'd like to test how it handles WiFi signal issues and disconnects to make sure it can reconnect properly to WiFi and MQTT.
Of course, the simplest way would be to just turn off my WiFi router, but I'm hoping to avoid that because I'm not the only one who uses WiFi in my house :)
So I was thinking, is there a way to shield the microcontroller itself from WiFi?
I tried fully enclosing it an aluminum foil, the WiFi signal still gets through.
Tried placing it in a stainless steel pot and covering it with a stainless steel lid, still works :)
I thought that would work like a Faraday cage, but it doesn't.
Is there a way to stop WiFi from reaching my Pi Pico W?

Comment: place it in a microwave oven

Comment: unplug the oven first to avoid costly mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Your steel-pot solution should work; if not, it was probably because you had wiring going outside of the pot, and this wiring was picking up & re-radiating the WiFi signal.

So you need to eliminate all external wiring, or if that isn't possible, use feed-through capacitors in the wall of the enclosure, which act as low-pass filters removing the RF.

If you don't mind spending a bit of money, get a 'screen box' or 'shield box', which will have RF gaskets and feed-through capacitors already fitted. They are used (amongst other things) for the testing of mobile phones, and often pop up on auction sites at quite low prices. The interior is generally fitted with a re-radiating antenna, that can be linked to an external WiFi antenna via an attenuator, allowing you to control the RF signal strength.

Answer (score 1):

Get another wifi access point and connect the raspberry pi to that for testing.

Used wifi routers can often be re-purposed as access points - just be sure to turn off DHCP and other discovery and routing features before connecting them to your wired LAN